# Is it safe to use WakefulIntentService 0.3.0 for pre-2.0 device support?

Tags: android

My app supports users down to 1.6 (API level 4) and I want to use WakefulIntentService for scheduled background checks of required data.  From a [blog post on Dec. 28 2010](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/12/28/wakefulintentservice-updated.html), Mark indicates the reasoning for dropping support in 0.4.0 and later.  From what I can tell, the only real concern with the method used in 0.3.0 is handling a crashing service.  If I were to make sure the service never crashed (try not to giggle) would that mean I could safely use 0.3.0, or are other issues afoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I were to make sure the service never crashed (try not to giggle)

:: covers mouth, stifles a pending guffaw ::

> would that mean I could safely use 0.3.0, or are other issues afoot?

Uh, well, it's more that I'm not supporting it on Android 1.x.

Since there have been other modifications, though, you might consider updating your copy of the current stuff to (try to) work on Android 1.x rather than using the older implementation. That should involve:

- Getting rid of the `@Override` annotation on `onStartCommand()`, as that might give you `VerifyErrors` when trying to load it on older Android versions
- Adding `onStart()` that just calls `onStartCommand()` and eats the return value

Two other notes:

1. It's better to ask questions regarding CommonsWare-specific stuff on [the `cw-android` Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android). I don't read *every* question on StackOverflow, but I don't miss anything on `cw-android`.
2. I'll be making a minor update to [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) by early next week, so keep tabs on the project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and for the info about the cw-android Google Group).  Naturally I'd prefer to use the latest version.  I'll take a stab at implementing your advice.  Of course, if you added a graceful fallback to future releases, that would be /really/ nifty.  :)